# Design pattern for refactoring

Tags: python, design-patterns, refactoring

I have those three functions and I find it ugly to repeat all the same code, this is not DRY at all.
At the same time, I'm not sure how could I refactor those functions to keep clear expression.
Could you recommend anything?

Thanks

```
def download_loc(instance, filename):
    username = instance.username_or_anonymous()
    slug = instance.slug
    filename_with_timestamp = filename_timestamped(instance, filename)
    return "%s/%s/stl/%s" % (username, slug, filename_with_timestamp)

def preview_loc(instance, filename):
    username = instance.username_or_anonymous()
    slug = instance.slug
    filename_with_timestamp = filename_timestamped(instance, filename)
    return "%s/%s/preview/%s" % (username, slug, filename_with_timestamp)

def screenshot_loc(instance, filename):
    username = instance.username_or_anonymous()
    slug = instance.slug
    filename_with_timestamp = filename_timestamped(instance, filename)
    return "%s/%s/screenshot/%s" % (username, slug, filename_with_timestamp)
```

Comment: you make the type (stl, preview and screenshot) another parameter and have one function

Comment: Look at what's the same, look at what's different, encapsulate each.

Answer (score 4):

Introduce a third function which takes the type name as a parameter. Personally I would just call that function, but if it is called from a lot of places there is value in wrapping it.

```
def loc(instance, filename, typename):
    username = instance.username_or_anonymous()
    slug = instance.slug
    filename_with_timestamp = filename_timestamped(instance, filename)
    return "{}/{}/{}/{}".format(username, slug, typename, filename_with_timestamp)

def download_loc(instance, filename):
    return loc(instance, filename, "stl")

def preview_loc(instance, filename):
    return loc(instance, filename, "preview")

def screenshot_loc(instance, filename):
    return loc(instance, filename, "screenshot")
```

Comment: Note that the `%` operator is deprecated in favor of `str.format`.